# How to format this SQL table?

Tags: sql

i have the following SQL table (below is an example of it) that i need formatted. I want to group up the customer Order ID so it only display every order once and i want the Order Complete column to be set to 1 if the 'balance' 
 value is equal or higher to the 'to be delivered' on every row that has the same order ID.

EDIT: Each row of customer ID can have different article numbers (i did not include the artnr in the table) so to check if the total balance > delivered is not enough, each row has to have balance enough to finally set the order complete to 1.

Is there a somewhat easy way to do this with SQL?

```
Customer Order ID   Customer        Balance To Be Delivered Pick Date   Delivery Date   Order Complete
119290          Customer A          40      40              37546       37911           0
118886          Customer B          4       4               37546       37911           0
119575          Customer B          0       1               37546       37911           0
119575          Customer B          34      22              37546       37911           0
118776          Customer C          934     600             37911       38277           0
P119630         Customer D          0       1               37911       38277           0
P119630         Customer D          0       1               37911       38277           0
119347          Customer E          0       10              37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          0       8               37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          8       8               37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          0       16              37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          0       16              37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          48      48              37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          48      48              37911       38277           0
119476          Customer F          48      48              37911       38277           0
```

the end result would be like this.

```
Customer Order ID   Customer    Pick Date   Delivery Date   Order Complete
119290          Customer A     37546        37911           1
118886          Customer B     37546        37911           1
119575          Customer B     37546        37911           0
118776          Customer C     37911        38277           1
P119630         Customer D     37911        38277           0
119347          Customer E     37911        38277           0
119476          Customer F     37911        38277           0
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe it's a Sybase SQL database, it's part of our ERP System that we use in our company. I've only been using SQL queries from it for a couple of months, mostly through Crystal Reports. At the moment all i've done is creating this new table from different already existing tables and put it in a procedure and i'm outputting it as a html table on one of our internal websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having *pick date* and *delivery date* that could differ between items on the same order, you need to decide if you want first or last date on the grouped list. I've picked one of each in this example.

```
  SELECT id,
    customer, 
    MIN(pick_date) AS first_pick, 
    MAX(delivery_date) AS last_delivery_date, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN balance >= to_be_delivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS complete
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY id, customer
```

**EDIT:** code refactored over and over again...

Try it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65028/9/0

Comment: i realised i forgot to include a vital part in my question so this will not work, see my edited section.

Comment: @Mattias ok, fixed it! Starting to look like a mess though :)

Comment: thanks! that worked. I got a followup question on this, is it possible to hide the order if all rows of it have less balance then needed to be delivered?

ie order complete can be either 0 as nothing can be delivered, 1 as one or more items can be delivered else hide the order completly.

Comment: Add this to the very end:
`HAVING MAX( CASE WHEN balance >= to_be_delivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in ANSI SQL

```
SELECT order_id,customer, pick_date, delivery_date,CASE WHEN SUM(old_order_complete) = COUNT(order_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS order_complete
FROM (SELECT order_id,customer, pick_date, delivery_date, CASE WHEN  balance >= to_be_delivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS old_order_complete
FROM your_table)a
GROUP BY order_id,customer, pick_date, delivery_date
ORDER BY customer;
```

Comment: i realised i forgot to include a vital part in my question so this will not work, see my edited section.

Comment: What is the data set for article number and what is the logic